# Node.js + Express - Can't connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I followed this basic example:

http://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/

Files were generated...they're all there. I ran it all step-by-step. No matter which browser I use, I get "Unable to connect" (Firefox) and "This webpage is not available ... ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" (Chrome) - it's just not working. I checked the generated bin/www file and it seems to indicate port 3000. However, I got *no* output when I ran "node app.js" after generating the site. Upon looking at that file, I noticed it pointed to the wrong path for Node on my system, so I changed it to the correct one:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('rwc:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error('Port ' + port + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error('Port ' + port + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  debug('Listening on port ' + server.address().port);
}
```

No dice. Nothing changed. No output when running "node app.js" and can't pull it up. I know node is there and correctly installed since I've already run a bunch of example code and played with it a bit.

On OS X Yosemite but my firewall is turned off.

What's going on? Surprisingly little info found when search on this too - makes me hesitant to build anything serious with Node.

Comment: I wouldn't be hesitant. 90% of computer error is user error. Node isn't the problem. When you run `node app.js`, you get no output at all? Also please update the question with the output received when you run `which node`.

Comment: What URL are you accessing? and please give the code that creates the server, will be helpful

Comment: Does the process stay running?  Are you running it from the command line so you can see it is still running.

Comment: Of course it's my error. It's obviously not as mature as more reliable technologies, so I should probably save it for personal projects, is my thinking. I've already read a book and followed a few tutorials, and found that between all of them, there was a lot of conflicting/outdated info. No output at all. Nothing happens and can't pull anything up in any browser. I've wiped it out and tried regenerating the site a couple of times.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:3000 and even tried http://localhost:3000. I also tried my local IP address. All the same result.

Comment: If you get no output at all, then you did something wrong in following the instructions provided. You should at least get a console log statement that the app is listening on whatever port you set it to.

Comment: You're probably right Paul, though there was no indication of a problem along any step of the way. No errors. Files are where they expected and look as expected. I'm tempted to remove express, node, and all of it - and start fresh.

Comment: Which file would that be? Added the bin/www file that was generated by express.

Comment: So just to clarify, installed node, express, and express-generator. Ran express ..., it generated a directory. You cd'd into it and ran `npm i`(install). once all dependencies were installed, you ran `node app.js` and received no output? Can you paste the command and what it does or doesn't return? We're currently using node.js on enterprise level applications with great success. You just need to use it for the right things and not use it for something it wasn't meant for.

Comment: Removing everything might be premature though. Hold off on that for a bit.

Comment: Just as a side note, to address the various comments about the maturity / reliability... I've experienced the exact same kind of problem before on literally every new technology I've tried. By "new" I mean "new to me", so this includes the first time I did Java, first time I did .NET, etc.  It's part of the learning curve.  If anything, outdated tutorials is a sign of growth and maturity in the framework. :D  That said, like @Seth, I've used Node for many applications, including some that required a good degree of stability & maturity, and I have no complaints.

Comment: Amen brother man. As everything has its quirks, so does node. But I agree, outdated tutorials is a great sign of growth. With node still growing everyday, it's not something to rule out. It's a great tool. Maybe for your next numeric computation or scientific evaluation project, don't use it though.

Comment: Seth - yes...did all that. I mentioned the command: "node app.js", like the tutorial directed. Reassuring to hear that you're having success w/ it. It's all very appealing - coming from a .NET and Java background myself. I've always loved js and server-side seems like a dream...just having trouble getting it off the ground. The book I've been reading (Node Web Development - Second Edition by David Herron) is great, but I've already found much outdated info in there...and it's only a year old, or so. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not appropriate for this thread, but I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed by the amount of information out there. Basically, I want to build a Node+Express+Sequelize (html -not- Jade) app on top of mysql - preferably with some separation of concerns. There are at least a million variations on how to do this in tutorials out there on the webs, and tons of outdated examples. What's a great source to learn from for this - a simple, straightforward example app that's up to date? Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, hit the docs and study web application architecture. Architecture is always up to date if it's a battle tested structure. The docs are also always up to date and provide everything you need to know. On top of that just get intimate with javascript as a language and commonJS. Just always use the latest and most stable modules. MVC pattern seems to be what you want and express 4 is rock solid for that. Tighten your commonJS knowledge and you'll have a modular application that will be very strong. I'll try and throw something together on github for you if I have time as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, Seth. Appreciate the help. I've been hitting it a little bit everyday. Getting better at fixing outdated code when I find it. I'm looking at going with Express for MVC, Sequelize over mySQL (or plain SQL), Angular on the front-end, and maybe a good RESTful service layer between the data and middle-tiers. Something loosely-coupled that would easily scale up. Been checking out Cluster but not sure if it's too experimental for production use, yet. I have some wiggle room on this project but don't want any big surprises. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that the tutorial you're following is very old. Express generator has changed it's structure immensely over time. It now utilizes `npm` to run the initial app commands, as you should. The scripts object in `package.json` is extremely handy for abstracting commands.

Simply `cd` into your example app and run:

`npm start`

You'll see the following in your terminal:

```
$ npm start

> example@0.0.0 start /Users/your-user/example
> node ./bin/www
```

and enjoy!

The rest of that tutorial aside from setting it up is still pretty accurate though. I'd consult the [docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html) above anything to be honest. Just my opinion though.

**Lastly** "I noticed it pointed to the wrong path for Node on my system, so I changed it to the correct one". You should change that back or it might fail.

Answer (score 2):

Also if one wants to keep the server running , then use nodemon

```
nodemon bin/www
```

Which will give same the o/p :

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www bin/wwww`
```